# Initial setup to cover all the options

Tags: ios, initialization

I want to call initialProperties to cover all options of it instance

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self initialProperties];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initialProperties];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initialProperties];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This my code.
question1: am i right?
question2: what the diffence between these?

Comment: Looks fine, assuming this is a UIView subclass... if you don't know the difference why are you doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make it.
In UIView init is exactly equal to [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero]
initWithCoder is called when use xib or storyboard
And initWithFrame as we all know